# Dativ vs. Akkusativ

Tags: grammatical-case

Folgender Satz:

> Wir laden sie zum Grillen in … Garten ein und sie bitten uns zu Partys
>   in … Haus.

Wie muss man hier richtig die Frage stellen? Geht man vom Verb aus und fragt *Wohin laden sie uns ein?/Wohin bitten sie uns?* oder bezieht sich der Ort (der Garten bzw. das Haus) aufs Grillen bzw. Partys (*Wo wird gegrillt?*/*Wo finden Partys statt?*)?

a) Wir laden sie zum Grillen in unseren Garten ein und sie bitten uns zu Partys in ihr Haus.

b) Wir laden sie zum Grillen in unserem Garten ein und sie bitten uns zu Partys in ihrem Haus.

Vielen Dank!

Comment: First half of the sentence is fine in both cases. What is the second half supposed to say?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler: steht so in einer Übungsgrammatik... im Sinne von "einladen" (nehme ich mal an)

Comment: OK, verstanden.  `und sie bitten uns [im Gegenzug] zu Partys in ihr Haus`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beides geht, und heißt in dem Fall praktisch das gleiche, aber die syntaktische Struktur ist anders.

Bei

> *Wir laden [zum Grillen] [in unseren Garten] ein*

sind *zum Grillen* und *in unserem Garten* unabhängige Argumente von *einladen*.  Beides sind dabei freie Angaben -- der Satz wäre auch ohne jedes einzelne denkbar.  Wir können sowohl fragen, wohin eingeladen wird (Garten), als auch wozu (Grillen).

In

> *Wir laden [zum Grillen [in unserem Garten]] ein*

ist *zum Grillen in unserm Garten* eine zusammengehörige Phrase, in der die Präpositionalphrase *in unserem Garten* den Kopf näher bestimmt.  Wir können fragen, wozu eingeladen wird (Grillen), und wohin zum Grillen eingeladen wird (Garten).  Man kann hier **nicht** *zum Grillen* einfach weglassen, ohne den Sinn zu ändern:

> *Wir laden in unserem Garten ein*

bedeutet, dass wir einladen, während wir uns in unserem Garten befinden.

Comment: Großartig! Vielen lieben Dank! Jetzt ist alles klar! =)

Answer (score 0):

Achtung, das ist reine Intuition. Begründen kann ich es nicht

> Wir laden sie zum Grillen in unseren Garten ein ...

vs

> Wir laden sie zum Grillen - in unserem Garten - ein ...

**in unserem Garten** ist in diesem Fall ein verkürzter Einschub (das **in unserem Garten** startfindet), während es oben nur eine adverb. Bestimmung des Ortes ist.

Im zweiten Satzeil ist es das Gleiche, nur das er Einschub ganz hinten steht.

Answer (score 0):

> Wir laden sie in unseren Garten ein ...

scheint mir gestelzt, auch wenn "zum Grillieren" gleich folgt und es klar wird. Es tönt: Sie haben die Erlaubnis unseren Garten zu betreten.

"jmd in etwas einladen" hat einen offiziösen Beiklang, während "jmd zu etwas einladen" eine nette Aufforderung sein.

> Wir möchten Sie zum Essen bei uns zu Hause einladen. (o. in unserem Haus)
>
> ?Wir möchten Sie in unser Haus zum Essen einladen.

Wobei genau betrachtet in diesem Standardfall wohl mit "zu uns zum Essen einladen" das Haus ganz weggelassen wird.

Also: Garten mit Dativ angeben, und nicht als Ziel der Einladung mit Akkusativ. (ausser man meint es so - grammatikalisch geht beides).